# Find the top level parent

Tags: php, arrays

I have a MySQL table with id, category_id (parent id), and url.

I have a class that looks something like this. I have removed all unnecessary functions.

```
class categoriesBuilder
{
    var $items = array();
    var $html  = array();

    function fetch_assoc_all( $sql )
    {
        $result = mysql_query( $sql, $this->conn );

        if ( !$result ){
            return false;
        }

         $assoc_all = array();

         while( $fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ){
                $assoc_all[] = $fetch;
        }

        mysql_free_result( $result );

        return $assoc_all;
    }

    function get_categories()
    {
        $sql = 'SELECT id, category_id, url FROM categories ORDER BY category_id, id;';

        return $this->fetch_assoc_all( $sql );
    }

    function get_category_string($root_id=0)
    {
        $this->html  = array();
        $this->items = $this->get_categories();

        foreach ( $this->items as $item )
            $children[$item['category_id']][] = $item;

        // loop will be false if the root has no children
        $loop = !empty( $children[$root_id] );

        // initializing $parent as the root
        $parent = $root_id;
        $parent_stack = array();

        while ( $loop && ( ( $option = each( $children[$parent] ) ) || ( $parent > $root_id ) ) )
        {
            if ( $option === false )
            {
                $parent = array_pop( $parent_stack );
            }
            elseif ( !empty( $children[$option['value']['id']] ) )
            {
                array_push( $parent_stack, $option['value']['category_id'] );

                $parent = $option['value']['id'];

                // HTML for menu item containing childrens (open)
                $this->html[] = $option['value']['url'] . "/";
            }
            else
            {
                $this->html[] = $option['value']['url'] . "/";
            }
        }

        return implode($this->html );
    }
}
```

I need a function that returns only the top level parent. there may be several sub categories.

i.e.

- category id 1

  - category id 3

    - category id 4
    - category id 5
- category id 2

  - category id 6

In this example if i entered 3, 4 or 5 into the function the output would be 1. if i entered 6 i would get 2.

I also need a similar function that shows all parent folders.

for example if i entered 3 i would get 1 but if i entered 4 or 5 i would get 1-3

Thanks for your help.

Comment: We're not going to write this for you.  What have you tried?

Comment: I have included a function i created to show all categories from an ID onwards. i just cant figure out how to reverse it

Comment: It's a shame you're not using PostgreSQL. In pg it's a simple task to track hierarchies using Common Table Expressions.

Comment: It is a shame! Unfortunately I'm forced into this setup. Does anyone have any pointers in PHP what so ever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your DB is like this:

(1, 0, URL1),
(3, 1, URL3),
(4, 3, URL4),
(5, 3, URL5),
(2, 0, URL2),
(6, 2, URL6)

Then you just need to walk up the list

e.g.

```
function get_top_parent($category_id, $root_id=0)
{
    // Grab the id's and category's
    $item_list = array();
    foreach($this->items as $item) {
        $item_list[$item['id']] = $item['category_id'];
    }

    $current_category = $category_id;

    while(TRUE) {
        if ($item_list[$current_category] == $root_id) {
            // Check to see if we have found the parent category.
            return $current_category;
        } else {
            // update our current category
            $current_category = $item_list[$current_category];
        }
    }

}

function get_parents($category_id, $root_id=0) 
{
    $parents = array();
    // Grab the id's and category's
    $item_list = array();
    foreach($this->items as $item) {
        $item_list[$item['id']] = $item['category_id'];
    }

    $current_category = $category_id;
    while(TRUE) {
        // Check to see if we have found the root category.
        if ($item_list[$current_category] == $root_id) {
            return $parents;
        } else {
            // update our current category and parents
            $current_category = $item_list[$current_category];
            array_unshift($parents, $current_category);
        }
    }

}
```

reworked to return URL  (I did not verify this code but it should work):

```
function get_top_parent($category_id, $root_id=0) 
{ 
    // Grab the id's and category's 
    $item_list = array(); 
    foreach($this->items as $item) { 
        $item_list[$item['id']] = array(
            'category_id'   => $item['category_id'],
            'url'           => $item['url']
        );
    } 

    $current_category = $category_id; 

    while(TRUE) { 
        if ($item_list[$current_category]['category_id'] == $root_id) { 
            // Check to see if we have found the parent category. 
            return $item_list[$current_category]['url']; 
        } else { 
            // update our current category 
            $current_category = $item_list[$current_category]['category_id']; 
        } 
    } 

} 

function get_parents($category_id, $root_id=0)  
{ 
    $parents = array(); 
    // Grab the id's and category's 
    $item_list = array(); 
    foreach($this->items as $item) { 
        $item_list[$item['id']] = array(
            'category_id' => $item['category_id'],
            'url' => $item['url']
        );
    } 

    $current_category = $category_id; 
    while(TRUE) { 
        // Check to see if we have found the root category. 
        if ($item_list[$current_category]['category_id'] == $root_id) { 
            return $parents; 
        } else { 
            $temp_array = array(
                'category_id'   => $current_category
                'url'           => $item_list[$current_category]['url']
            );
            // update our current category and parents 
            $current_category = $item_list[$current_category]['category_id']; 
            array_unshift($parents, $temp_array); 
        } 
    } 

}
```

The first function returns the URL,  the second function should return an array of arrays...  You will have the standard index, with "category_id" and "url" as nested/sub arrays...   (If in doubt, just do a print_r of the return value to see what I mean)

again, i checkced the origional code but not the update...

Comment: Your welcome...  Just one word of caution, be careful with the WHILE(TRUE) statments... They could result in an endless loop that times out your script (if the structure of the db heirarchy is bad or missing parent cateogires)...  You may want to setup some sort of counter or timer that will kill the loop (e.g. "RETURN FALSE")

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  Do you know how to return the url instead of the id? would i need an each loop in the while loop?

Comment: for get_top_parent you can do it with do{..} while($item_list[$current_category]['category_id']>$root_id) instead of while(true){..}